# How do I parse a string representing a sequence of arithmetic operations?

Tags: java, string, double

I am working on a personal project and I want to take in userinput that looks like this :

```
   1.0+2.5+3--4
```

and format it to something like this :

```
   1.0 + 2.5 + 3 - -4
```

so far I am using the .replace("+") to .replace(" + ") and doing that for all of the operands but the problem is it makes the user input into this:

```
  1.0 + 2.5 + 3 - - 4
```

Is there a way that I can make it with the negative signs. I want to do this so I could parse the numbers into doubles and add and subtract them later on.

my code for it :

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class StringMan {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String check = "-a1 +a2 +       a3 +-a5";
    check  = check.replace("--", "+");
    System.out.println(check);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(check);
      boolean expr = matcher.find();
      String str = matcher.replaceAll(" ");
      System.out.println(str);



}

   }
```

output is:

```
   -a1 +a2 -       a3 +-a5
   -a1 +a2 - a3 +-a5
```

the problem is I want the output to look like this: 
       -a1 + a2 - a3 + -a5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using regular expressions and their "group" functionality. I would actually remove all whitespace to make things easier, take it out of the equation, one less thing to deal with. And obviously I would recommend simplifying the string, replacing "--" with "+", "*+" with "*" and so on.

now you can use a regex on your cleaned up string.

```
Pattern firstPat = Pattern.compile("(((\\+|-)?)\\d+(.\\d+)?)");//for matching the first number, leading sign is optional
Pattern remainingPat = Pattern.compile("(\\+|-)(\\d+(.\\d+)?)");//for remaining numbers, leading sign is mandatory.
Pattern remainingPatWithExtOps = Pattern.compile("(\\*|/|\\+|-)(-?\\d+(.\\d+)?)");//for remaining numbers, accommodating multiply and divide with negative signs(positive signs should have been cleaned out)

Matcher match = firstPat.matcher(inputString);
```

now you can iterate through the string using the `match.find()` method. and then use `match.group(1)` to get the sign/operation, and use `match.group(2)` to get the number...

So...

```
Double firstnum;
boolean firstNumSigned = false;
if(match.find())
{
    firstNum = Double.parse(match.group(0));// Parsing handles possible sign in string. 
    //obv check for exceptions during this and double check group num
    String tmp = match.group(1);
    firstNumSigned = tmp.equals("+") || tmp.equals("-");
}
else
{//no match means the input was probably invalid....
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("What the heck were you thinking inputting that?!");
}
match = remainingPat.matcher(inputString);//use our other pattern for remaining numbers
if(firstNumSigned)
{
    match.find();//a signed first number will cause success here, we need to ignore this since we already got the first number
}
Double tmpRemaingingNum;
String operation;
while(match.find())
{
    operation = match.group(1);
    tmpRemainingNum = Double.parse(match.group(2));
    //Do what you want with these values now until match.find() returns false and you are done
}
```

PS: code is not tested, im fairly confident of the regex, but I'm not 100% sure about the grouping brackets on the first pattern.. might need to experiment

Comment: String a = "-1.0+-10";
  Pattern firstPat = Pattern.compile("(+|-)?(\\d+(.\\d+)?)");//for matching the first number, leading sign is optional
  Pattern remainingPat = Pattern.compile("(+|-)(\\d+(.\\d+)?)");//for remaining numbers, leading sign is mandatory. add * and / if you want to accommodate those functions.

  Matcher match = firstPat.matcher(a);
  System.out.println(match);

Comment: string a should have been simplified to turn "+-" into "-" and like I said, i didnt test this code...

Comment: oh wait nvm, i think i see what you are getting. you might have to escape the "+" since its a quantifying meta character. edits coming up.... edits done.

Comment: but how do I put it all together ? thank you so much for your help btw :)

Comment: Edited and expanded to show some logic... its not tidy at all and i havent even compiled it. but it should show the general flow. Note how tricky the grouping brackets are, the brackets in the regex determine the group number, I am not sure I counted them correctly so you might have to adjust those brackets/numbers....

Comment: you should also note that ive changed the grouping brackets in my original code snippet now that ive thought about it more. so if youre copying and pasting (and somehow this code is working) youll want to re-copy those expressions. from above which are now slightly different

Comment: its crashing if I do "-4+4 +1"

Comment: first of all that has whitespace. I said *you* should normalize the string first. the regex will not do that for you and it is not built to handle whitespaces in the input. Second of all I havent compiled this code and I am not going to, so without more info I cant tell you what is wrong with it. I recommend googling for a "Java Regex Tutorial" and using a good debugger to figure out whats going wrong and how to make the program work. Sorry i cant be more help, but its  getting late for me to be on this website. PS: if the answer does end up being helpful id appreciate an upvote.

Comment: yeah I sure will when I get the answer thanks for your help but I am 75% sure I am not going to take this path. Thanks though.

Comment: gotta love being downvoted for no reason after putting a bunch of effort into a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: I am sorry but that wasn't me I don't know who it was.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, you can handle `--` by just replacing them with `+`:

1. Take input as a string from the user
2. Remove all white space
3. Replace all `--` with `+`
4. Continue parsing as desired

Comment: problem is that user input can be this too`-4+5-6'

Comment: I don't see how that is a problem.

Comment: That's not a problem. However `6*-2` may be.

Comment: should I post what I have so far ? I had the -- part done but before part I was trying to figure out because I want spaces between them so I can apply the .split(" ");

Answer (score 0):

Start by replacing -- with +, which is mathematically equivalent. Or start by replacing -- with - -, which would keep - and 4 together.

Answer (score 0):

Check this ,
Read both strings and integers in between operators like '*,--,-,+"
We can read both integers and characters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Pattern remainingPatWithExt=Pattern.compile("(\\p{L}\\p{M}*)[\\p{L}\\p{M}0-9^\\-.-?_+-=<>!;]*");
    String check = "a1+a2+--a7+    a3 +-a5";

      Matcher matcher = remainingPatWithExt.matcher(check);
      while( matcher.find())
      {
          System.out.println(matcher.group()); 
            //use  matcher.group(0) or matcher.group(1)
      }

}
```

### output

a1
a2
a7
a3
a5