# regex giving error less than 2

Tags: java, regex

okay so I set up this regex to take exponential and give me back doubles but it crashes if I give it less than two

```
String sc = "2 e 3+       1";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sc);
boolean check = matcher.find();
sc = matcher.replaceAll("");
String sc1;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*[eE][-+]?[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(sc);
m.find();
int starting = m.start(); //where first match starts
int ending = m.end();//where it ends
String scientificDouble = sc.substring(starting, ending);
String replacement = "" + Double.parseDouble(scientificDouble);
sc1 = sc.replace(scientificDouble, replacement); //first time

//this block must go in a loop until getting to the end, i.e. as long as m.find() returns true
m.find();
starting = m.start(); //where next match starts
ending = m.end();//where it ends
scientificDouble = sc.substring(starting, ending);
replacement = "" + Double.parseDouble(scientificDouble);
sc1 = sc1.replace(scientificDouble, replacement);//all other times,
```

if I give it sc = "2e3 + 1 " it crashes saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available
at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Matcher.java:325)
at StringMan.main(StringMan.java:32)
```

Comment: My regexes always give me less than 3. *runs*

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Why does the comment say "this block must go in a loop" when it doesn't?

Comment: I thought that is what m.find does it keeps repeating until it finds it ? lol ur a khan I am a khan too :D

Comment: I suggest you forget about using regexes for now; they're just getting in your way.  In particular, disregard [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542628/how-do-i-parse-a-string-representing-a-sequence-of-arithmetic-operations/7542700#7542700) to your previous question and start over from scratch.

Comment: I did I got my equation spaced out and before I do that I just want to get rid of the darn expo and make it a complete double than I can just go on my way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to [@Stephen C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543991/regex-giving-error-less-than-2/7544107#7544107), `find()` will not magically loop the block of code for you. Since you want to execute the same block of code as long as `find()` returns `true`, you should use a [while loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html):

```
String source = "2e3+1, 2.1e+5, 2.8E-2";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?[eE][\\-\\+]?[0-9]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);
while (matcher.find()) {
   String match = matcher.group();
   double d = Double.parseDouble(match);
   System.out.println(d);
}
```

(using regex correctly suggested by [@Martijn Courteaux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543991/regex-giving-error-less-than-2/7544002#7544002))

This particular example prints all parsed `double` to `System.out` - you can do what you need with them.

Please upvote the cited answers if this is helpful.

Comment: but I would like it to build the string back up to what it was without the Expon. If you could show me how to do that than this is the Perfect answer and not ignore other numbers like 1+1E3 should make it 1 + 1000

Comment: The perfect answer will be for you to go out and do the reading/learning/practice on your own. Start with the [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) - this would've taught you about the `while` loop.

Comment: the thing is I have been practicing trying to fix my broken code up and now I am just stuck and asking for help thats all sorry if that seems like trouble to u but bear with me please.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't fit the spaces in your string. I tried to fix your regex, try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?[eE][\\-\\+]?[0-9]*");

String sc = "2e3+1"; // Whitespaces cleared
```

Comment: still crashed :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Matcher.java:325)
 at StringMan.main(StringMan.java:32)

Answer (score 1):

> still crashed :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available ...

That's because you are ignoring the result of the `m.find(...)` calls.  If `m.find` returns `false`, then the pattern match failed and methods like `Matcher.start` `Matcher.end` and `Matcher.group` will throw `IllegalStateException` if called.

This will all be explained in the Javadoc for `Matcher` and its methods.  I strongly recommend that you take the time to read it.

Comment: should I put it in a while I did that first and I couldn't figure out which one to put in the while

Comment: If you are trying to read *multiple* numbers, then yes.  Otherwise, you should use an `if` statement.